# Creating default object from empty value in PHP?

Tags: php, object-oriented, array

Consider the following code.

```
$car = (object)[
   'general' => [
        'interior' => [
            'seats' => 'destroyed'
        ]
    ]
];

$exteriorProperties = [
    'hood' => 'shiny',
    'windows' => 'dirty'
];

foreach($exteriorProperties as $key => $prop){
    $car->{'other'}->{'exterior'}->{$key} = $prop;
}
```

This is a scenario where I'd like to add properties to an object, a few layers deep at a time, while iterating through some other data. If it doesn't exist, it will just create it, if it does it will override. PERFECT!

Unfortunately, this will throw the warning:

> Creating default object from empty value

I could resolve the issue by checking first if the property exists like so:

```
foreach($exteriorProperties as $key => $prop){
    if(!isset($car->other))
        $car->other = (object)[];
    if(!isset($car->other->exterior))
        $car->other->exterior = (object)[];
    $car->other->exterior->{$key} = $prop;
}
```

This is not my ideal solution. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution. Currently, I'm using this:

```
@$car->{'other'}->{'exterior'}->{$key} = $prop;
```

to suppress the warnings but I'm worried about compatibility in the future.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution to this scenario?

Comment: Don't use arrays as the answer below suggest, use object properly. Arrays are only good for local code, shared outside a file or class means you are writing keys manually, having to remember them, miss one or two, typo. Good IDE with auto complete and objects with getter/setter are a happy dev world.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use arrays.

```
$car = [
   'general' => [
        'interior' => [
            'seats' => 'destroyed'
        ]
    ]
];

$exteriorProperties = [
    'hood' => 'shiny',
    'windows' => 'dirty'
];

foreach($exteriorProperties as $key => $prop){
    $car['other']['exterior'][$key] = $prop;
}
$car = (object) $car;
```

Anyway, the object conversion will only convert the outermost array. The nested arrays are still arrays.

```
\is_array($car->general); // true
```

Why you need it to be shapeless objects anyway? Either define classes for those objects or treat them as arrays is the simple answer.

Btw `$car->{'other'}` is really weird way of writing `$car->other`...

Comment: I suppose you're right, I just hate getting locked into arrays all the time. The `$car->{'other'}` is because most of my property keys are coming from string variables. such as `$car->{$var1}->{$var2}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid the iterated conditional operations by processing all data as arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oG0t7))

```
$car = json_decode(
    json_encode(
        array_replace_recursive(
            (array)$car, 
            ['other' => ['exterior' => $exteriorProperties]]
        )
    )
);
```

When only coverting the top level from object-type to array-type you can just cast it with `(array)`. If you need to convert all levels -- json encode the whole object, then decode that string to an array.  When you are done processing, use `json_` functions to revert the data to object-type.

I still find this a little clunky (perhaps just as clunky as your conditional approach).  The benefit in the above is in the recursion; if your data depth changes, you won't need to alter the processing script.  Ask yourself if you *actually* need to use an object.  If coding is simplified with a different data-type, perhaps have a rethink/refactor.

P.s. DEFINITELY don't write the stfu operator (`@`) into your code.  In nearly all implementations, the technique is avoidable (this is one of those cases) and projects with such syntax are categorized/presumed as low quality by knowledgeable developers.

Comment: Thanks, good assessment. I unfortunately could not choose anything but objects since a previous programmer has coded it as such.